# How to update table with another table but no common field

Tags: mysql

I need to update the value in TableB, but the data in common field are not exactly the same. This is what i've tried so far

```
UPDATE TableB (`value`) SET (value * rate)

| TableA |  
Rate    t
2   2001
3   2002
4   2003

| TableB |  
value   t
1       2001-1
2       2001-2
3       2001-3
1       2002-1
2       2002-2
3       2002-3
1       2003-1
2       2003-2
3       2003-3
```

Result (Sorry I didnt check carefully for my data)

```
| TableB |  
value   t
2       2001-1
4       2001-2
6       2001-3
3       2002-1
6       2002-2
9       2002-3
4       2003-1
8       2003-2
12      2003-3
```

Comment: Is it a one time job?

Comment: ya, I want to make it for one time job, but any solutions will be welcome,

Comment: Your expected output confused me. Would you please explain this?

Comment: Your output is wrong according to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try This

```
TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TableB.t,'-',1))
```

Your query

```
UPDATE TableB JOIN TableA ON TableA.t =    
TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TableB.t,'-',1))SET TableB.value= TableB.value * TableA.rate
```